# Trouble setting up basic Pinia store with Vue options API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, pinia

I am new to Pinia, and am having trouble setting up just a basic store. I have been following Pinia's own documentation, and cannot seem to read any state whatsoever from the vue component I'm mapping to the Pinia store.

In my app I have:

```
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
export default function initApp(el) {
    let app = createApp(MenuApp);
    app.use(router).use(createPinia()).mount(el);
}
```

I set up a super basic Pinia store, just to get started:

```
import {defineStore} from 'pinia';

export const useTestPiniaStore = defineStore('testStore', {
    state: () => {
        return {
            name: 'bob'
        }
    },
})
```

In my vue component I have:

```html
<template>
    <div class="menu-page">
        <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapState } from 'pinia';
import useTestPiniaStore from '@store/modules/piniaStore';

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState(useTestPiniaStore['name']),
  }
}
</script>
```

Pinia appears in my Vue dev tools, but no stores appear within it, and I get the error
`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')`

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. If anyone can give some pointers that would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[`mapState()`](https://pinia.vuejs.org/api/modules/pinia.html#mapstate) requires **two** arguments, but you've passed it only one.

The 1st argument should be `useTestPiniaStore`, and the 2nd should be an array of state properties to map (or an object). It looks like you're trying to reference `name` from `useTestPiniaStore`, which would be `undefined`.

Your computed prop should look like this:

```html
<script>
import { mapState } from 'pinia'
import { useTestPiniaStore } from '@/store'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState(useTestPiniaStore, ['name']), 
  },
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-use-pinia-store-option-api?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

Comment: Thanks, but now I keep getting a "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$id')" .. I added in mapStores to my component as well.

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have luck with mapState as well when I was trying to set it up with both Pinia and Vue using Options API.

What worked for me was using mapStores. Here's an example from the [cookbook](https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/options-api.html#giving-access-to-the-whole-store):

```
import { mapStores } from 'pinia'

// given two stores with the following ids
const useUserStore = defineStore('user', {
  // ...
})
const useCartStore = defineStore('cart', {
  // ...
})

export default {
  computed: {
    // note we are not passing an array, just one store after the other
    // each store will be accessible as its id + 'Store'
    ...mapStores(useCartStore, useUserStore)
  },

  methods: {
    async buyStuff() {
      // use them anywhere!
      if (this.userStore.isAuthenticated()) {
        await this.cartStore.buy()
        this.$router.push('/purchased')
      }
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am on Vue3 and my stores is on Pinia (setup method). I have a few components that are based on Options API and I wanted to use the functions (actions) and data values in the Pinia store.
Suggestion of dominik-serafin and as per cook book https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/options-api.html using mapStores meets my requirement.

for eg my Pinia has a Store with id 'ix'
in my component...

```
...
import { mapStores } from 'pinia'
import { useixStore } from '@/stores/ix'
...
export default {
    props: ...
    data...
    computed: {
        ...mapStores( useixStore ),
        ...
```

As per cookbook "By default, Pinia will add the "Store" suffix to the id of each store. You can customize this behavior by calling the setMapStoreSuffix()."

So now I am able to access my entire store using this.ixStore.xyz... in component script and by using ixStore.xyz... in component template.